# Ptr in function parameter[in]

Tags: c++, gazebo-sensor, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Beginner Tutorial: Velodyne Sensor](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5)

```
public: virtual void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
      // Just output a message for now
      std::cerr << "\nThe velodyne plugin is attach to model[" <<
        _model->GetName() << "]\n";
    }
```

I am new to C++, i want to know more about the **Ptr in function parameter[in]**, it can be seen everywhere.

Any gentle guide or hint would be appreciated.

Thanks for your kindness

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16307/ptr-in-function-parameter%5Bin%5D/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ModelPtr is a custom type declaration. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/bae84f76b4ad7a6a7cecaeb3e76e545b8c8d5f3e/gazebo/physics/PhysicsTypes.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#PhysicsTypes.hh-91), you can see the `typedef` and how `ModelPtr` is equivalent to `boost::shared_ptr<Model>`. In a nutshell, a `ModelPtr` is a shared pointer to a model object. [Here's a quick tutorial](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/smart-pointers-in-boost/184401507) about boost smart pointers.

An `ElementPtr` is also a custom type, another shared pointer to an `sdf::Element`. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/4ecab3417a5be2ecdc3394db523ef9a47dddcf6b/include/sdf/Element.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Element.hh-43), you can see the `typedef` in SDFormat.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2017-06-06**:
Thanks for your helpful answers!